# Powershell read one tab in Excel and Export as CSV

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I want to read a hidden tab in excel file and copy that tab and export it to csv.

I did this command, but it only output the meta data of that tab

```bsh
$file = Get-ChildItem $sp | Where-object {$_.Name -match $patten} | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -first 1    
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.open($file.Name)    
$wb.Sheets.Item(4) | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Users\path\test.csv"
```

how should i get the actually content in that Tab (index No.4) and save as `test.csv` ?

Comment: Have a look at [Worksheet.SaveAS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas) and the available [Excel file formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

Answer (score 1):

Well you were close. This should do it.

```
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(4)
$ws.SaveAs("c:\Users\path\test.csv", 6)
```

Make sure, the path exists.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to make the spreadsheet visible first.

use some code similar to this:

ws.sheet_state = 'visible'

This is a guess!